Scan in any desk
Good evening. How are you? I think I fell for a scam. Can you help me? I hired someone to scan my PC to see if they could find any signs of keyloggers or something regarding some invasions I have been experiencing. The expert told me to open AnyDesk and send my IP number. It was on December 24th around 4 PM. According to him, 4 technicians would conduct the search. That’s all, I didn’t click to accept the connection or anything. He said it would be done through some type of backdoor, etc. They didn’t send me any kind of report or anything. Just a call saying that nothing was found. The guy said it was 4 hours of service and that he would do another test on December 27th. However, on December 26th, he sent a message saying he had run another 2 hours of research and found nothing new. However, believe it or not, the computer was turned off. There was a misunderstanding about which day it would be. Then I asked for reports or screenshots. They also didn’t send anything. I think I fell for a scam. I invested 3500 money. Can you give your opinions? Thank you."

This expert was part of a cybersecurity scammer group. I would Reset your system and restore personal files from a offline backup. Contact your bank for the refund. Explain you were taken advantage of through a cybersecurity scam. Calling your bank is really your only option. Do yourself a favor do not take call from them, they will contact you, and threaten you. There isn’t anything we can do to help you. Contacting your bank is the solution to your being scammed but isn’t really worth making it a permanent answer. NEVER allow anyone to remotely access your system.

It's a legal matter, not one SuperUSer can answer. Contact your local law enforcement --  but note that, even in countries with excellent law enforcement, it's not common to recover any loss.

Hello. Thank you for your reply. Maybe I didn't make my question clear. I would like to know if this type of connection exists. Is it possible to access my computer this way? Without me clicking accept connection.
